# How can I add a class to each <pre> element before running syntaxhighlighter?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
    $.fn.addTemplateSetup(function () {
        this.find('pre').each(function (i) {
            SyntaxHighlighter.highlight({}, this);
        });
    });
```

It finds each  element and then runs SyntaxHighlighter on it.

Before highlighter runs I want to change each `<pre>` that is inside a `<div>` with a class of text into `<pre class='brush: plain'>`

Should I do this inside the first function, should i use another this.find?

Comment: did you mean `style="brush: plain`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.fn.addTemplateSetup(function () {
    $("pre", this).addClass("brush: plain");
    this.find('pre').each(function (i) {
        SyntaxHighlighter.highlight({}, this);
    });
});
```

Or

```
$.fn.addTemplateSetup(function () {
    this.find('pre').each(function (i) {
        this.addClass("brush: plain");
        SyntaxHighlighter.highlight({}, this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Be aware that you're adding two classes there. One named `brush:` and the other `plain`.

Comment: @JamieDixon That's correct. The classname does seem odd, but I assume it's formatted that way so as the syntax highlighter plugin reads it as a setting.

Comment: $("pre",this) is equivalent to this.find("pre") the implementation of £("pre",this) simply calls this.find("pre")

Comment: That's correct, however from a performance point of view I'm not sure off the top of my head whether it's quicker to apply a class to a jQuery oobject of elements, or each element individually in a loop. My initial though was that the former is quicker, hence I put that version first :)

Comment: Hello Rory, The first example looks very clear. How would I change this if I wanted to just make this work inside of divs with a class of "text"?

Comment: The only performance difference is that $("pre",this) takes slightly longer to call because it has to execute code before it ends up calling this.find("pre"). The object either returns is the same so stick to one of them and chain the calls then you don't have to select twice, which is probably going to be more expensive than the difference between the two

Answer (score 3):

```
$.fn.addTemplateSetup(function () {
    this.find('pre').each(function () {
        this.addClass("brush: plain");
        SyntaxHighlighter.highlight({}, this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you select using $ you get a set of elements and each operation you perform on the selection will be performed on all elements.
so `$("pre").addClass("myClass")` will add the class 'myClass' to all pre elements in the document. Further the operation returns the selection it self so you can chain operations like so:
`$("pre").addClass("myClass").css("font-weight","bolder")` which would add the class and set the CSS property font-weight to bolder

The exception to this is when returning a value. E.g. when doing something like `$("input").val()` the value of the first input element will be returned

So in your particular case you need to select all the pre elements add the class and the highlight

```
$.fn.addTemplateSetup(function () {
        this.find('pre')
            .addClass("brush: plain")
            .each(function () {
               SyntaxHighlighter.highlight({}, this);
        });
});
```

However since your class looks more like you trying to apply some inline styling I've included how to do that as well

```
$.fn.addTemplateSetup(function () {
        this.find('pre')
            .css('brush', 'plain')
            .each(function () {
               SyntaxHighlighter.highlight({}, this);
        });
});
```

the reason why I've put addClass/css before each is that addClass/css will call each on the selection it's applied to. If addClass is used inside the each function it's going to call each on a selection of one element which I'd expect to be slower than iterating the entire collection twice. The number of visits to each element is the same in both cases and I would object to either in a review